# How to disable or uninstall open-iscsi from 16.04 server?

Tags: 16.04

How do you disable or remove the *open-iscsi* package (specifically `iscsid`) WITHOUT removing the *ubuntu-server* package?

---

```
# apt remove open-iscsi
```

..results in removal of package *ubuntu-server*.

---

```
# apt-get remove open-iscsi
```

..also results in the removal of package *ubuntu-server*.

Answer (score 1):

[There is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1630946) regarding the dependency between `open-iscsi` and `ubuntu-server`. The bug has been resolved, but only for Ubuntu 18.10. In 16.04 `apt` will not allow you to do what you want.

But you can disable the `iscsid` service so it isn't running:

```
sudo systemctl --now disable iscsid.service
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this worked or not; I got four lines of warnings as: ``insserv: warning: current {start,stop} runlevel(s) ({empty,0 1 6 S}) of script `iscsid' overrides LSB defaults ({S,0 1 6}).`` 

Once this was done, `systemctl` by itself still listed `open-iscsi.service` as `failed`; disabling `open-iscsi.service` with `--now` too didn't change that (and gave much the same output but doubled to eight lines of warnings). Will this resolve with a reboot?

Comment: Does not work...